# How to set up an automated mechanism to find build breaks?

Tags: build, build-automation

In a team where multiple people are working on same file or different files of the same solution it is quite natural that build break happens.. But how to have an automated mechanism where we can find build breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [CI Factory](http://cifactory.org/joomla/) to setup a CruiseControl.NET server.  Then have everyone install [CCTray](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/CCTray) and you can all get notifications of automated builds and see the current status.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should take a look at [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration).

Answer (score 0):

You have to build on an automated and regular basis. Have a look at build automation tools. This depends a little bit on the technologie you use, for us [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is fine (continuous integration is also a keyword for search). You can trigger a build every night or even every changeset in your repository. This should give you instant feedback on brocken builds.